# InfoPath - User Enters ID and lookup performed

Tags: list, infopath

I have a form that I'm developing where I'd like the user to be able to enter a unique ID number in a particular field that will then pull data from a separate list on a separate site and populate a number of fields (the unique ID is common to both lists).

They'd then be able to use this lookup data to submit a new item to the list then infopath is associated with after suggesting changes to the values as required.

Is this type of functionality possible? I've seen articles like the following but I can't find anything that tells me if a user mandated ID can be used to lookup data from another site.

https://brainspire.com/how-to-pull-in-sharepoint-lookup-additional-fields-into-infopath-form/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ab7503b-83f0-429c-bfcd-a7d73d3a1cda/infopath-display-info-from-another-list-in-new-item-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious